# SoapUI 5.2.0 how to set header property

Tags: rest, groovy, header, soapui

I have a test case, in the first testStep I make a request. I retrieved the JSESSIONID in the response of the first request and now I want to put it as a "cookie" property in the header of all my others testStep requests. How can I do it?

```
log.info "$jsessionid"

for (testStep in testRunner.testCase.getTestStepList()){
    if (testStep.getName() != "Request 1" && testStep.getName() != "Groovy Script") {
        //set the JSESSIONID in the request header property "Cookie"
    }
}
```

My others testStep have some values in their header

- Connection : keep-alive
- Proxy-Connection : keep-alive
- Accept-Encoding : UTF8
- Accept : application/json
- etc.

I want to add the "cookie : JSESSIONID=MYVALUE" in the list, or replace it if the property already exists.

Comment: you could perhaps add a small part of the request header of your "other" test step. Or at least specify if the "cookie" element is already present or you need to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to set the "Cookie" property in the header of every other testStep. The property is added in a list, this way it will replace older cookie values.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.*

//(...) 
//Retrieve the JSESSIONID and put it in a variable

log.info "$jsessionid"

for (testStep in testRunner.testCase.getTestStepList()){
    if (testStep instanceof RestTestRequestStep && testStep.getName() != "Request 1" && testStep.getName() != "Groovy Script") {
        def list = []
        list.add(jsessionid)
        def headers = testStep.testRequest.requestHeaders
        headers["Cookie"] = list
        testStep.testRequest.requestHeaders = headers
        log.info testStep.testRequest.requestHeaders["Cookie"]
    }
}
```